# For two connected closed sets whose intersection is non-empty, is their union connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If two closed sets are not disjoint, is their union connected? How can we prove it or disprove it?

Updated:

Sorry for making it unclear. I mean for two connected closed sets whose intersection is non-empty, is their union connected?

Comment: Are you sure that that's the question that you wanted to ask?

Comment: In title yo say disjoint and in the question you say not disjoint.

Comment: Specify if you are doing hypothesis for the two closed sets. I am not sure you want them to be not connected, for example.

Comment: @nicomezi Yeah I mean they are connected actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{0,1\}$ and $\{1,3\}$ are not disjoint and they are closed sets in $\mathbb R$. Their union is not connected.

For the question in the title take $\{0,1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$.

If you are considering  connected closed sets then the answer is as follows: if they are disjont then their union cannot be connected and if they are not disjoint then their union is necessarily connected.

Comment: But if 2 closed sets are connected and not disjoint, then there union is also connected, right?

Comment: @FareedAF Then, you could even drop the "closed" hypothesis, for that matter.

Comment: @FareedAF OP didn't say that his sets are connected!

Comment: Sorry for missing the "connected" hypothesis. Would you please give proof that if 2 closed sets are connected and not disjoint, then their union is also connected?

Comment: @Thinkpad Whenever two connected sets have a point in common their union is connected. There is no need for the sets to be closed.